# Responsive Navigation Sub Heading Overlapping

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive, responsive-nav

I created a responsive navigation menu with sub-headings, but the sub-headings overlap when hovered or tapped. I would like to know how I can fix this, making sure that they don't overlap and appear normally. I did use a jquery plugin in for the double tap to go property, could the problem lie in there? Thank you!

Here is a picture of what is happening:
Sub Heading Overlap:

[image]

Here is a codepen,

http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/VKkQxy

and below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

<title>Test Nav Bar</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon (1).ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

<style>

a {
text-decoration: none;
}


ul, li {

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    box-sizing:border-box;  /** add this **/
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
 -ms-box-sizing:border-box; /** add this **/
   background-color: #4484CE;
}

#nav > a {
    display: none;
}


#nav li {
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

#nav span:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0.313em solid transparent; /* 5 */
    border-bottom: none;
    content: '';
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: -0.313em; /* 5 */
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul {
    height: 30px;
    background:#93C178;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block ;
    color: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > a, #nav > ul:not( :hover ) > li.active > a {
    background-color: #F9CF00;
}

/* second level */

#nav li ul {
    background:#93C178;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}

#nav li:not( :first-child ):hover ul {
    left: -1px;
}

#nav li ul a {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #4484CE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul:not( :hover ) li.active a {
    background:#FCFCFC;
    color: #465C8B;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1192px ) {
    #nav {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 12px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1047px ) {
    #nav {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 10px;    
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 864px ) {
    #nav {
        font-size: 9px; 
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 9px; 
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 9px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 804px ) {
    #nav {
        font-size: 8px; 
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 8px; 
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 8px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 704px ) {
    #nav {
        font-size: 7px; 
    }

    #nav > ul > li > a {
        font-size: 7px; 
    }

    #nav li ul a {
        font-size: 7px; 
    }
}

 @media only screen and ( max-width: 62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
}

}

 @media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* 640 */ {

html {
    font-size: 75%; /* 12 */
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    background-color: none;
}

#nav > a {
    width: 3.125em; /* 50 */
    height: 3.125em; /* 50 */
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #93C178;
    position: relative;
}

#nav > a:before, #nav > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    top: 35%;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    content: '';
}

#nav > a:after {
    top: 60%;
}

#nav:not( :target ) > a:first-of-type, #nav:target > a:last-of-type {
    display: block;
}

/* first level */

#nav > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#nav:target > ul {
    display: block;

}

#nav > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0.833em; /* 20 (24) */
}

#nav > ul > li:not( :last-child ) > a {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4484CE;
}

/* second level */

#nav li ul {
    position: static;
    padding: 1.25em; /* 20 */
    padding-top: 0;
}
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation"><img src="hamburger button.png" width="48" height="48" alt="menu button" longdesc="hamburger button.png" /></a>
    <a href="#" title="Hide navigation"><img src="hamburger button.png" width="48" height="48" alt="menu button" longdesc="hamburger button.png" /></a>
<ul>

<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">About Us</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="principal's_message.html">Principal's Message</a></li>
    <li><a href="mission_and_vision.html">Mission and Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="our_history.html">Our History</a></li>
    <li><a href="staff_directory.html">Staff Directory</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">School Offices</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="attendance_office.html">Attendance</a></li>
    <li><a href="counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li>
    <li><a href="main_office.html">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="magnet_office.html">Magnet</a></li>
    <li><a href="bridge_office.html">Bridge</a></li>
    <li><a href="english_learner's_office.html">EL</a></li>
    <li><a href="itd_office.html">ITD</a></li>
    <li><a href="library.html">Library</a></li>
    <li><a href="parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
    <li><a href="nurse's_office.html">Nurse</a></li>
    <li><a href="safety_ofifice.html">Safety</a></li>
    <li><a href="plant_manager's_office.html">Plant Manager</a></li>
    <li><a href="cafeteria.html">Cafeteria</a></li>
    <li><a href="student_store.html">Student Store</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Academics</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li>
    <li><a href="culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li>
    <li><a href="departments.html">Departments</a></li>
    <li><a href="counseling_office.html">Counseling</a></li>
    <li><a href="library.html">Library</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Programs</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com" target="new">IB</a></li>
    <li><a href="middle_years_programme.html">The Middle Years</a></li>
    <li><a href="ste[+a]m_program.html">STEA[+a]M</a></li>
    <li><a href="vei-jv.html">VEI-JV</a></li>
    <li><a href="gate_sas_program.html">GATE/SAS</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://lacerstars.org/" target="new">LACER</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Students</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
    <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "dress_code.html">Dress Code</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "cougar_code.html">Cougar Code</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "attendance_policy.html">Attendance Policy</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com/learner-profile.html" target="new">IB Learner Profile</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">Student Handbook</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "library.html">Library</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "map.html">Map</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/site/default.aspx?PageType=3&ModuleInstanceID=1555&ViewID=7B97F7ED-8E5E-4120-848F-A8B4987D588F&RenderLoc=0&FlexDataID=16590&PageID=845" target="new">Food Menu</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "student_store.html">Student Store</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://www.bancroftmiddleschool.org/2015-16yearbook/index.html" target="new">Yearbook</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Parents</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href= "parent_bulletin.html">Parent Bulletin</a></li>
    <li><a href= "cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a></li>
    <li><a href= "parent_center.html">Parent Center</a></li>
    <li><a href= "calendar.html">Calendar</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">District Handbook</a></li>
    <li><a href= "school_site_council.html">SSC Council</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "school_decision_making_council.html">SDM Council</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "elac.html">ELAC</a></li> 
    <li><a href= "contact_teachers.html">Contact Teachers</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
(function ($, window, document) {
  'use strict';
  $.fn.doubleTapToGo = function () {
    if (typeof (window.ontouchstart) === 'undefined' && !navigator.msMaxTouchPoints && !navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/windows phone os 7/i)) {
      return false;
    }

    this.each(function () {
      var curItem = false;

      $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        var item = $(this);
        if (item[0] !== curItem[0]) {
          e.preventDefault();
          curItem = item;
        }
      });

      $(document).on('click touchstart MSPointerDown', function (e) {
        var resetItem = true,
          parents   = $(e.target).parents(),
          i;

        for (i = 0; i < parents.length; i + 1) {
          if (parents[i] === curItem[0]) {
            resetItem = false;
          }
        }

        if (resetItem) {
          curItem = false;
        }
      });
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery, window, document));
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#nav li ul li {
  background: #000; //You have to change your background color of second ul li
}

#nav li ul {
  padding: 0; //Remove padding as well
}
```

**Changes:**

[image]

Online [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lubeno/edit?html,css,js,output):

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this!

Comment: I don't have enough rep for it to show, but I did do it :)

Comment: Can you please send me a link to what you did to fix it so I can input the changes properly? I added the bg color to what I thought was the correct place, but the pop-up sub- headings appear at the bottom. Thanks!

Comment: I have done only two changes and it's already mentioned in the answer box. If it not clear so kindly tells me then I will make an online demo for you.

Comment: Can you please? Because I used the > shortcut in my code, so it's hard to tell what things really are, Thanks again!

Comment: Now you can check online demo as well in answer box. Thanks !

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: hey, this change caused the flexslider below my navbar not to show. Can you please help with that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403948/responsive-navbar-hides-flexsldier OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382992/responsive-nav-bar-hides-element-below-it